# how to get the element from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have an array which is

```
myArr = [
    {
        "root": ["1", "6"],
        "element": "Apple"
     }, {
        "root": ["2", "7"],
        "element": "Banana"
     }, {
        "root": ["3", "8"],
        "element": "Orange"
     }, {
        "root": ["4", "9"],
        "element": "WaterMelon"
     }, {
        "root": ["5"],
        "element": "Kiwi"
     }
]
```

Just wondering if I have a string which is '3' which match with one of the root array above and I want to get the element from the array above, how should I do it in javascript? Any help? thanks

Comment: so what have you tried so far?

Comment: You need to specify what you have tried so far. Maybe provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question, for better clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can filter your array that way + `destructing` your root to check it includes "3" or not :

```js
const s = "3"

const myArr = [{
  "root": ["1", "6"],
  "element": "Apple"
}, {
  "root": ["2", "7"],
  "element": "Banana"
}, {
  "root": ["3", "8"],
  "element": "Orange"
}, {
  "root": ["4", "9"],
  "element": "WaterMelon"
}, {
  "root": ["5"],
  "element": "Kiwi"
}];

const res = myArr.filter(({
  root
}) => root.includes(s))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply filter the array to get the element:

```js
const myArr = [
    {
        "root": ["1", "6"],
        "element": "Apple"
     }, {
        "root": ["2", "7"],
        "element": "Banana"
     }, {
        "root": ["3", "8"],
        "element": "Orange"
     }, {
        "root": ["4", "9"],
        "element": "WaterMelon"
     }, {
        "root": ["5"],
        "element": "Kiwi"
     }
];

const ele = myArr.filter(arr => arr.root.includes("3"));
console.log("Required", ele);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this gets you started:

```
myArr.forEach((x)=>{ 
    x.root.forEach((j)=> { 
        if(j=='3'){console.log( x.element);}
    })
})
```

Iterate the main array, then for each element iterate the "root" array. If it matches the '3', return the element field of the main item

Answer (score 0):

```
const myArr = [
  {
    root: ["1", "6"],
    element: "Apple"
  },
  {
    root: ["2", "7"],
    element: "Banana"
  },
  {
    root: ["3", "8"],
    element: "Orange"
  },
  {
    root: ["4", "9"],
    element: "WaterMelon"
  },
  {
    root: ["5"],
    element: "Kiwi"
  }
];

const stringToFind = "3";

const elemList = myArr
  .filter(obj => obj.root.includes(stringToFind))
  .map(obj => obj.element);

console.log(elemList);
```